# How to make a function/class from an imported library accessible for all the libraries imported below in Dart?

Tags: dart

Suppose I have this:

**benchmark.dart:**

```dart
library benchmark;
benchmark() {...}
```

**app.dart:**

```dart
import 'benchmark.dart'; // functions from this lib are now accessible in this file
export 'benchmark.dart'; // does this make them accessible in all files imported below?

import 'model.dart';

void main() {
  doSomething();
}
```

**model.dart**

```dart
doSomething() {
  benchmark(); // => Error, no such method, unless
               //    I import 'benchmark.dart' above in this file!
}
```

Is this the right behavior? How do I make benchmark accessible *without* importing the lib in **model.dart**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the imports in every library you want to use other libraries.
What you might do is to join several files to one library using `part 'model.dart';` (parent file) and `part of app;` (linked file).
Then the types and functions imported in the parent file are available in all files of this library.